# Is $\phi$ being injective sufficient for the substitution formula $\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)}g(x)\ dx = \int_a^b g(\phi(t))\phi^\prime(t)\ dt$?

Tags: calculus

Is $\phi$ being injective sufficient for the substitution formula $\int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)}g(x)\ dx = \int_a^b g(\phi(t))\phi^\prime(t)\ dt$ to be true?  Working with Riemann integral.  If not please provide counter example.

Comment: You work with the Riemann integral?

Comment: @Fakemistake yes - edited for clarification.

Comment: It isn’t sufficient to be invective, it must also be a $C^1$-function. Otherwise the integral on the right hand side does not exist.

Comment: @Fakemistake well yeah thats the standard hypothesis, I guess a injective $\phi$ with non integrable derivative would be a counter example...  But I'm terrible for thinking up functions - any idea?

Comment: If $\phi$ is differentiable with integrable derivative (this is the least requirement for the RHS to make sense) and $g$ is continuous, this is always true (and has nothing to do with injectivity). If $g$ is discontinuous, then  $\phi$ can be as nice as you want and the conclusion can still fail, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, injectivity is not needed, and injectivity alone is not sufficient. You can see the statement of the theorem on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_a_single_variable). The important hypotheses are (1) $\phi:[a,b]\to I$ is differentiable with an integrable derivative (a special case of that is when $\phi$ is continuously differentiable); (2) $g:I\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous; and (3) $\phi\left([a,b]\right)$ is a subset of the interval $I$ where $g$ is defined.

Here's an example where we make the substitution $x=t^2$:
$$\int_4^9\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt x-1}\,dx=\int_a^b\frac{\sqrt{t^2}}{\sqrt{t^2}-1}(2t)\,dt $$
You can take $a=2,b=3$ or $a=-2,b=-3$. However, you can't take $a=-2,b=3$ because $\phi\left([-2,3]\right)=[0,9]$ (where $\phi(t)=t^2$) while the integrand on the LHS is not defined and continuous on this interval. That said, making $\phi$ injective provides an advantage because you can determine the new integration limits by applying $\phi^{-1}$ to the integration limits of the original integral.

Comment: "differentiable with an integrable derivative (in particular, ϕ is continuously differentiable)" This sounds like you're saying that differentiable with integrable derivative implies continuously differentiable. I'd suggest a rewording.